# Finding conflicts between vehicles departures and free times

Tags: python, r, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

|  | ID | Test | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | EJ MR-1 | 2018-11-13 21:39:08 | 2018-11-14 05:42:34 |
| 2 | 2 | VN MR-1 | 2018-11-14 09:07:19 | 2018-11-14 09:25:22 |
| 3 | 3 | VN MR-1 | 2018-11-14 09:07:19 | 2018-11-14 09:20:22 |
| 4 | 4 | GR MR-1 | 2018-02-04 19:22:40 | 2018-02-04 19:38:38 |
| 5 | 5 | KO MR-1; KO MR-2 | 2018-11-14 10:04:51; 10:04:03 | 2018-11-14 10:22:42; 10:06:38.. |
| 6 | 6 | KO MR-1 | 2018-11-14 09:43:23 | 2018-11-14 10:22:42 |

I want to compare the first row and second row to check if they were any conflicts when a vehicle was in use. The issue is that sometimes I have multiple vehicles used by a single id and I don't know how to make the comparison between a row with two start time and end times and a row with one start time and end time. Any clues on how I should approach the problem?

I tried many different ways to reshape the dataframe but nothing that worked.